# Masking UITableViewCell (paralax effect)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my App I am trying to get a paralax effect in my table. (e.g it's background) which contains a blurred map for each entry.

How I've set it up is i have a `XIB` with a `UITableViewCell` and have added the labels to the contentView. Then in code I add the image to the backgroundView. (The backgroundView doesn't exist, and I create an "empty view" to where I add the image).

Then I add the `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` to the image view.

This works. But, since the image has the same dimensions as the table view cell, when a person tilts the phone and the paralax effect kicks in white edges appear. As you can see in the image below.

[image: White edges with paralax]

That is not something I want. So I thought, well I could just put a bigger image in the backgroundView. This works while I am not in editing mode. But in editing mode the background image overlaps partially with the delete button. As seen here:

[image: Overlap in editing mode]

So I thought, I should clip the backgroundView containing the image view. Which I've done with the following code:

```
self.backgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or this

```
// Create a mask layer and the frame to determine what will be visible in the view.
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGRect maskRect = self.bounds;

// Create a path with the rectangle in it.
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);

// Set the path to the mask layer.
maskLayer.path = path;

// Release the path since it's not covered by ARC.
CGPathRelease(path);

// Set the mask of the view.
self.backgroundView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But neither solutions work. It looks like it is not being clipped. Is there an other way to go about this?

Comment: set borderColor and borderWidth to exactly know the backGroundView frame in simulator.from that you can know is the problem is with the frame or clipToBOunds. try once

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I have made a screenshot in the simulator while "Color Blended Layers" was checked. Perhaps this is helpful. http://cl.ly/TN32